# How should I initialize ngbDatepicker with formControlName instead of [(ngmodel)]

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I need to use ReactiveForms, with `[formGroup]` and `formGroupName="field"`

```
<form [formGroup]="generalForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
  formControlName="dateIni" ngbDatepicker #a="ngbDatepicker">
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
generalForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
this.generalForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  dateIni: ['', Validators.required],
  dateFin: ['', Validators.required],
  registerDateLimit: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

}

In my code, I tried to put a default value:

```
public dateIni: { year: 2017, month: 8, day: 8 };
```

or

```
@Input() dateIni: { year: 2017, month: 8, day: 8 };
```

but it is not taking the default value and all the docs only mention the case with template forms.

Any Idea how should I do it ?

Comment: You need FormGroup with control named dateIni

Comment: I will update my question withe the code

Comment: @Antoniossss is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  dateIni: ['', Validators.required],
```

you need to put your initial value here like

```
 dateIni: ['2014-01-01', Validators.required],
```

in  correct format

Comment: Tx ! just change it with:        dateIni: [{'year': 2018, 'month': 12, 'day': 12}, Validators.required] for NgbDatePicker

Comment: I don't know this component, but I do know more or less how reactive forms works ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem and resolved using below code snippet

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-profile',
      templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
    })
    export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    
     generalForm: FormGroup;
    
    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private datePipe: DatePipe) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {
    
       this.intilizeForm();
    
        const dateIni = "2018-12-08"
        const iniYear =  Number(this.datePipe.transform(dateIni, 'yyyy'));
        const iniMonth =  Number(this.datePipe.transform(dateIni, 'MM'));
        const iniDay =  Number(this.datePipe.transform(dateIni, 'dd'));
        this.generalForm.controls.dateIni.setValue({
          year: iniYear ,
          month: iniMonth ,
          day: iniDay
        });
      
    }
    
      intilizeForm(): void {
      // Here also we can set the intial value Like dateIni:[ {year:2018,month:08, day: 12}, ..... 
        this.generalForm = this.fb.group({
           name: ['', Validators.required],
           dateIni: ['', Validators.required],
           dateFin: ['', Validators.required],
           registerDateLimit: ['', Validators.required],
         
        });
    
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is integrated with Angular forms and works with both reactive and template-driven forms. So you could use `[(ngModel)]`, `[formControl]`, `formControlName`, etc. Using `ngModel` will allow you both to get and set selected value

Example with `formControlName`

**HTML**

```
<input
  formControlName="date_input" 
  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
  ngbDatepicker
  #de="ngbDatepicker">
```

**Typescript**

```
public myForm: FormGroup; 

// ...

// > converting the date String to Date object
let date = new Date('2022-12-01T00:00:00+00:00'); 

this.myForm.setValue({

  // ...

  date_input : {
    year: date.getUTCFullYear(), // output: 2022
    month: date.getUTCMonth() +1, // output: 12
    day: date.getUTCDate() // output: 01
  },

  // ...

});
```